# TypeError: can't concat str to bytes. List to txt file

Tags: python, twitter, utf-8, typeerror

I get `TypeError: can't concat str to bytes` when I try to write list of words into txt file.

Below is what's on the book and it returned `TypeError` then I tried differently and it worked.

```
# Error Code
f = open('words.txt', 'w')
for word in stemmed:
    try:
        f.write(word.encode('utf-8') + '\n')
    except UnicodeEncodeError, e:
        print 'Enconding error ' + word + '\n'
f.close()

# Working Code
f= open('word.txt','w',encoding= 'utf-8')
for word in stemmed:
    try:
        f.write(word+'\n')
    except UnicodeEncodeError as e:
        print('Encoding Error' + word + '\n')
f.close()
```

What is the difference between two codes? 
It seems like `# Working Code` does save list of words into `txt` file but does not print any encoding error?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the first snippet (the one from the book) is written for Python 2.
In Python 2, byte strings (type `str`) and Unicode strings (type `unicode`) can be mixed – it works sometimes, sometimes it raises a UnicodeError, and sometimes it produces garbage text ("mojibake").

However, you are apparently running Python 3 (which is good!), where the two string types are incompatible: you can't mix byte strings (type `bytes`) and Unicode strings (type `str`).

The "working code" snippet looks fine to me, no need to change anything (although using the `with` statement for opening the file would be nice).
It doesn't produce any UnicodeError because there are very rare cases where encoding to UTF-8 fails.
If there was an error, it would be handled by your `except` clause.

There's probably no need to fully understand why the first snippet fails.
Just ditch the "error code" and try to find a more recent Python book that covers Python 3.
Python 2 is going to be discontinued soon, you shouldn't have to bother about it if you're a new Python learner.

Answer (score -1):

error code ,the result of the code `word.encode()` is a bytes like object,so ,you can't concat str and bytes.
working code :
the word and '\n' have been encoded before they were put into txt file.

Comment: How can I fix the Error code to work? Working Code returns no error but not sure if it's actually doing `except UnicodeEncodeError as e:`

Comment: `# Error Code
f = open('words.txt', 'wb')
for word in stemmed:
    try:
        f.write(word.encode('utf-8') + b'\n')
    except UnicodeEncodeError, e:
        print 'Enconding error ' + word + '\n'
f.close()`

Comment: @goudan why don't you edit your answer to include this piece of code? It's almost unreadable as a comment.